# Is localStorage/sessionStorage considered NoSQL database?

Tags: javascript, html, database

according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API , there are essentially two Web Storage APIs, localStorage and sessionStorage, they are used to store key/value pairs.

And I learned that according to https://aws.amazon.com/nosql/key-value/

> A key-value database is a type of nonrelational database that uses a
>   simple key-value method to store data.

So my question is, is localStorage/sessionStorage considered NoSQL database?

Comment: It kind of is, only it's not a database :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not a database. It's just a variable associated to the window object. In the AWS text, it says "a key value database is a...", but a variable is not a database.

Comment: what prevents localStorage/sessionStorage to be considered a database?

Comment: @JojiI I think there are big differences of a local storage and a database. DBMS (databases manager systems, like mysql, mongodb, postgresql, etc) are programs that store information, provide a language to update-query that information, and execute standalone or inline with other programs. The last part of this definition is what probably make us classify Local Storage as not a DBMS,  because it is functionality code that run inherently dependant on each browser and as libraries of it. 
Of course you could use local storage, as a database. As you can use a fork to take a screw out.